# Programmatically transferring files to an MTP android device (python or ruby)

Tags: android, python, ruby, mtp

What is the simplest way to send files (preferably over USB) from a pc to an MTP android device (3.0+). Preferably in python or ruby, but I can adapt if needed. I'd also like to avoid using adb, as it adds extra steps on the users end.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Windows as of now, but cross platform support would be a plus. Should also mention that while I'd like to avoid adb I CAN have an app running on the android device to facilitate the transfer.